# select last observation from longitudinal data

Tags: r

I have a data set with several time assessments for each participant. I want to select the last assessment for each participant. My dataset looks like this:

```
ID  week  outcome
1   2   14
1   4   28
1   6   42
4   2   14
4   6   46
4   9   64
4   9   71
4  12   85
9   2   14
9   4   28
9   6   51
9   9   66
9  12   84
```

I want to select only the last observation/assessment for each participant, but I only have the number of weeks as an indicator for each participant. How is this possible to do in R (or excel?)

thanks in advance,

niki

Comment: As an aside, please make sure you're doing something sensible with this data; just taking the last available assessment can lead to very wrong inferences, depending on why you're missing data and what you're looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one base-R approach:

```
do.call("rbind", 
        by(df, INDICES=df$ID, FUN=function(DF) DF[which.max(DF$week), ]))
  ID week outcome
1  1    6      42
4  4   12      85
9  9   12      84
```

---

Alternatively, the `data.table` package offers a succinct and expressive language for performing data frame manipulations of this type:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key="ID")

dt[, .SD[which.max(outcome), ], by=ID] 
#      ID week outcome
# [1,]  1    6      42
# [2,]  4   12      85
# [3,]  9   12      84

# Same but much faster. 
# (Actually, only the same as long as there are no ties for max(outcome)..)
dt[ dt[,outcome==max(outcome),by=ID][[2]] ]   # same, but much faster.

# If there are ties for max(outcome), the following will still produce
# the same results as the method using .SD, but will be faster
i1 <- dt[,which.max(outcome), by=ID][[2]]
i2 <- dt[,.N, by=ID][[2]]
dt[i1 + cumsum(i2) - i2,]
```

---

Finally, here is a `plyr`-based solution

```
library(plyr)

ddply(df, .(ID), function(X) X[which.max(X$week), ])
#   ID week outcome
# 1  1    6      42
# 2  4   12      85
# 3  9   12      84
```

Comment: Nice responses.  I was trying to think of how to do this with plyr or aggregate and fail because I can't figure out how to return outcome with out hacking it together.  +1

Comment: @TylerRinker -- Would you take a look at the plyr solution I just added? I mostly end up using base-R or data.table, so might be missing some obvious improvement to it.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thank you for your responses. Works great.

Comment: @MatthewDoyle -- Very clever. As I familiarize myself with data.table, I'm noticing that many of the speediest constructs use a couple of `dt[]` operations instead of just one. In other applications, I'd seen this with `dt[dt[], ]` and `dt[]dt[]`, but this (using the nested call to get a logical vector) is new. (Think I may have seen something similar using `dt[dt[,,which=TRUE]]`). Anyways, thanks for the suggestion and (as I've said before) do feel free to edit any of my data.table related posts at any time. Cheers.

Comment: @Josh Hi. I remember your previous comments about editing so I felt confident to go ahead this time, great. Btw my surname is with w not y (I don't mind, just saying because the @ didn't work because of that, I just saw your comment by chance). This particular trick isn't the prettiest, is it. Have some ideas to improve: `.I` would be nice to add, and/or being a bit cleverer with `.SD` so that the natural syntax you used is just fast anyway as it should be, ideally. That's one reason a lot is packed into `[]` so that internally we can do better optimisation in the future.

Comment: @Josh And the `[[2]]` isn't ideal either. That's what `drop=TRUE` will do (with a speed advantage) when `drop` is added.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Apologies about getting your name wrong, but glad you found this anyway.  I just realized the method you added is equivalent only as long as there are no ties for `max(outcome)`. I added a method that **will** produce identical results even in the presence of ties.  Also, glad to hear you are planning a `drop=` option. Long term, figuring out how to make `.SD` operations just as fast would be quite a coup, since the syntax it allow **is** so much more natural. Sounds tricky to implement, though!

Comment: Ah you got me, good point. The correction with `cumsum` assumes that each group is contiguous, though? I'm not sure it's possible to cope with non-contiguous groups without `.I` holding the rows from `DT` that `.SD` corresponds to. And actually my way doesn't cope either, does it. Hm.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Doesn't having the `key="ID"` ensure that the relevant groups will be contiguous?  Unless I'm wrong about that, I think both your way and mine do cope with *that* issue, at least...

Comment: Yes you're right. But our solutions rely on that. Perhaps using `by=key(DT)` would make that clear.

Answer (score 10):

If you're just looking for the last observation per person ID, then a simple two line code should do it. I am up always for simple base solution when possible while it is always great to have more than one ways to solve a problem.

```
dat[order(dat$ID,dat$Week),]  # Sort by ID and week
dat[!duplicated(dat$ID, fromLast=T),] # Keep last observation per ID

   ID Week Outcome
3   1    6      42
8   4   12      85
13  9   12      84
```

Comment: This is a high quality answer that deserves more up-votes.  When it comes to `R`, I appreciate answers that don't involve installing new packages, etc.  Thanks for adding your two cents.

Answer (score 2):

Another option in base: `df[rev(rownames(df)),][match(unique(df$ID), rev(df$ID)), ]`

Comment: great thanks, first one works perfect. using the second i get some cases replicated, no clue why.

Comment: Just here for interest... I'd stick with Josh's! Will look at the dupes issue though..

Comment: `grep` wasn't really appropriate for exact matching of numerics.. `x==df$ID` does a better job.

Comment: Was this intended to get the (ID, week) combos for (1, 6), (4, 12), and (9, 12) like Josh (and myself) obtained in our versions? I got the lowest (first) week values from your second command: (1, 2), (4, 2), and (9, 2).

Comment: jbaums the first answer works but the second response does not return the correct response.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @BryanGoodrich... not my finest moment. Duly deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I can play this game. I ran some benchmarks on differences between *lapply*, *sapply*, and *by*, among other things. It appears to me that the more you're in control of data types and the more basic the operation, the faster it is (e.g., lapply is generally faster than sapply, and as.numeric(lapply(...)) is going to be faster, also). With that in mind, this produced the same results as above and may be faster than the rest.

```
df[cumsum(as.numeric(lapply(split(df$week, df$id), which.max))), ]
```

Explanation: we only want which.max on the week per each id. That handles the contents of *lapply*. We only need the vector of these relative points, so make it numeric. The result is the vector (3, 5, 5). We need to add the positions of the prior maxes. This is accomplished with *cumsum*.

It should be noted, this solution is not general when I use *cumsum*. It may require that prior to execution we sort the frame on id and week. I hope you understand why (and know how to use *with(df, order(id, week))* in the row index to achieve that). In any case, it may still fail if we don't have a unique max, because which.max only takes the first one. Therefore, my solution is a bit question begging, but that goes without saying. We're trying to extract very specific information for a very specific example. Our solutions can't be general (even though the methods are important to understand generally).

I'll leave it to trinker to update his comparisons!

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the data.table package. It should be very fast, even with larger data sets.

```
setkey(DT, ID, week)              # Ensure it's sorted.
DT[DT[, .I[.N], by = ID][, V1]]
```

Explanation: `.I` is an integer vector holding the row locations for the group (in this case the group is `ID`). `.N` is a length-one integer vector containing the number of rows in the group. So what we're doing here is to extract the location of the last row for each group, using the "inner" `DT[.]`, using the fact that the data is sorted according to `ID` and `week`. Afterwards we use that to subset the "outer" `DT[.]`.

For comparison (because it's not posted elsewhere), here's how you can generate the original data so that you can run the code:

```
DT <- 
  data.table(
    ID = c(rep(1, 3), rep(4, 5), rep(9, 5)),
    week = c(2,4,6, 2,6,9,9,12, 2,4,6,9,12), 
    outcome = c(14,28,42, 14,46,64,71,85, 14,28,51,66,84))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to use split and tapply a bit more to become more acquainted with them.  I know this question have been answered already but I thought I'd add another solotuion using split (pardon the ugliness; I'm more than open to feedback for improvement; thought maybe there was a use to tapply to lessen the code):

```
sdf <-with(df, split(df, ID))
max.week <- sapply(seq_along(sdf), function(x) which.max(sdf[[x]][, 'week']))
data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y) y[x, ], max.week, sdf)))
```

I also figured why we have 7 answers here it was ripe for a benchmark.  The results may surprise you (using rbenchmark with R2.14.1 on a Win 7 machine):

```
# library(rbenchmark)
# benchmark(
#     DATA.TABLE= {dt <- data.table(df, key="ID")
#         dt[, .SD[which.max(outcome),], by=ID]},
#     DO.CALL={do.call("rbind", 
#         by(df, INDICES=df$ID, FUN=function(DF) DF[which.max(DF$week),]))},
#     PLYR=ddply(df, .(ID), function(X) X[which.max(X$week), ]),
#     SPLIT={sdf <-with(df, split(df, ID))
#         max.week <- sapply(seq_along(sdf), function(x) which.max(sdf[[x]][, 'week']))
#         data.frame(t(mapply(function(x, y) y[x, ], max.week, sdf)))},
#     MATCH.INDEX=df[rev(rownames(df)),][match(unique(df$ID), rev(df$ID)), ],
#     AGGREGATE=df[cumsum(aggregate(week ~ ID, df, which.max)$week), ],
#     #WHICH.MAX.INDEX=df[sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) which.max(x==df$ID)), ],
#     BRYANS.INDEX = df[cumsum(as.numeric(lapply(split(df$week, df$ID), 
#         which.max))), ],
#     SPLIT2={sdf <-with(df, split(df, ID))
#         df[cumsum(sapply(seq_along(sdf), function(x) which.max(sdf[[x]][, 'week']))),
#         ]},
#     TAPPLY=df[tapply(seq_along(df$ID), df$ID, function(x){tail(x,1)}),],
# columns = c( "test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self","sys.self"), 
# order = "test", replications = 1000, environment = parent.frame())

          test replications elapsed  relative user.self sys.self
6    AGGREGATE         1000    4.49  7.610169      2.84     0.05
7 BRYANS.INDEX         1000    0.59  1.000000      0.20     0.00
1   DATA.TABLE         1000   20.28 34.372881     11.98     0.00
2      DO.CALL         1000    4.67  7.915254      2.95     0.03
5  MATCH.INDEX         1000    1.07  1.813559      0.51     0.00
3         PLYR         1000   10.61 17.983051      5.07     0.00
4        SPLIT         1000    3.12  5.288136      1.81     0.00
8       SPLIT2         1000    1.56  2.644068      1.28     0.00
9       TAPPLY         1000    1.08  1.830508      0.88     0.00
```

**Edit1:**  I omitted the WHICH MAX solution as it does not return the correct results and returned an AGGREGATE solution as well that I wanted to use (compliments of Bryan Goodrich) and an updated version of split, SPLIT2, using cumsum (I liked that move).

**Edit 2:**  Dason also chimed in with a tapply solution I threw into the test that fared pretty well too.

Comment: Although to make the tapply solution work for what the OP wanted you'd technically have to sort by week if it wasn't already sorted.  In this case it was sorted by week so oh well.

Comment: Huh? This table appears repeat each test 1000 times on a very small dataset. Why are the results of any use (in any way whatsoever) in practice?  You need to run a _single_ test of each method, on a _large_ dataset. _That's_ what matters.