# Subset row and column at the same time

Tags: r, data.table

I'm a bit surprised by how `data.table` works:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.2  For help type: help("data.table")
> dt <- data.table(a=11:20, b=21:30, c=31:40, key="a")
> dt[list(12)]
    a  b  c
1: 12 22 32
> dt[list(12), b]
    a  b
1: 12 22
> dt[list(12)][,b]
[1] 22
```

What I'm trying to do is obtain the value of a single column (or expression) in rows matched by a selection. I see that I've got to pass the key as a list as a raw number would indicate a row number and not a key value. So the first of the above is clear to me. But why the second and the thirs subset expression yield different results seems rather confusing to me. I'd like to get the third result, but would exect being able to write it the second way.

Is there any good reason why subsetting a data.table for rows and columns at the same time will always include the key value as well as the computed result? Is there a syntactically shorter way to obtain a single result except by double subsetting as above?

I'm using data.table 1.8.2 on R 2.15.1. If you cannot reproduce my example, you might as well consider a factor as key:

```
dt <- data.table(a=paste("a", 11:20, sep=""), b=21:30, c=31:40, key="a")
dt["a11", b]
```

Comment: I can't run `dt[list(12)]` : error: ```Error in `[.data.table`(dt, list(12)) : 
  typeof x.a (integer) != typeof i.V1 (double)```. I use data.table version 1.8.0

Comment: But this works and is very clear: `dt[a == 12]` and `dt[a == 12, b]`

Comment: @cafe876, I believe the data.table manual advises against that syntax, as it will prevent binary search and require sequential search instead. Still a nice syntax where performance is of no great concern, so perhaps you'd better turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: Re my first comment: in data.table 1.8.0, `dt[J(12)]` does what `dt[list(12)]` does in your example, with a slight difference of adding an "indx" column...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding this question:

> Is there any good reason why subsetting a data.table for rows and columns at the same time will always include the key value as well as the computed result?

I believe that the (good enough for me) reason is simply that Matthew Dowle hasn't *yet* gotten around to adding that option (likely because he has prioritized work on much more useful features such as ":= with by").

In comments following [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471744/select-last-observation-from-longitudinal-data/9471898#comment12058952_9471898), Matthew seemed to indicate that it is on his TODO list, noting that "[this] is what `drop=TRUE` will do (with a speed advantage) when `drop` is added".

Until then, any of the following will get the job done:

```
dt[list(12)][,b]
# [1] 22
dt[list(12)][[2]]
# [1] 22
dt[dt[list(12), which=TRUE], b]
# [1] 22
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. That feature is [FR#1757](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1757&group_id=240&atid=978).

Comment: After the export from R-Forge to GitHub it's now [FR#648](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/648)

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to use:

```
dt[a == 12]
```

and

```
dt[a == 12, b]
```

This will work as expected, but it prevents binary search and requires sequential search instead (is there a plan to change this behavior ??), making it potentially slower.

---

**UPDATE Sep 2014: now in v1.9.3**

From NEWS :

> `DT[column==values]` is now optimized to use `DT`'s key when `key(DT)[1]=="column"`, otherwise a secondary key (a.k.a. index) is automatically added so the next `DT[column==values]` is much faster. `DT[column %in% values]` is equivalent; i.e., both `==` and `%in%` accept vector values. No code changes are needed; existing code should automatically benefit. Secondary keys can be added manually using `set2key()` and existence checked using `key2()`. These optimizations and function names/arguments are experimental and may be turned off with `options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)`.

Comment: Re parenthetic question: maybe but only in the very distant future. v1.8.2 now has a `datatable.optimize` feature which makes some optimizations on `j`; e.g. `mean` and `lapply(.SD,...)` are much faster by auto converting the expression to faster forms (as per data.table wiki). If people like it and no gremlins appear then that theme could be continued to convert `a==2` to `J(12)` if `key(dt)[1]=="a"`. But many other things are higher priority.