# Select from a DataFrame the last observation from rows belonging to the same series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a DataFrame in Python similar to this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '0': ['monday', 1],
    '1': ['monday', 5],
    '2': ['monday', 2],
    '3': ['tuesday', 1],
    '4': ['tuesday', 3]
}, orient='index', columns=['day', 'value'])
```

And I want to extract the last observation/element for each of the days as defined for example by the value column, so:
`df = df.sort_values(['day','value'])`

How to do that efficiently on a large DataFrame? An extremely slow example of the desired effect would be:

```
indices = []
for day in df['day'].unique():
    indices.append(list(df[df['day'] == day].index)[-1])

df.loc[np.array(indices)]
```

Which yields:

```
    day value
1   monday  5
4   tuesday 3
```

I'm aware of this answer: [select last observation from longitudinal data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471744/select-last-observation-from-longitudinal-data), but it's in R.

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the original order of the index? (i.e. 1,4)

Comment: In my specific case no, so I haven't considered that explicitly but I think it is reasonable to assume that it is a desirable effect of the operation in general if it doesn't hinder performance.

Comment: I think it depends on how you see it. If you only want the observational data from a row (which is what you seem to write in your question) I think a new index is fine and not unexpected. While keeping the original index is expected if you want to fetch the actual row, imo at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specifying column `day` with parameter `last`, also if necessary default ordering of days create [`ordered categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#sorting-and-order):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    '0': ['monday', 1, 4],
    '1': ['monday', 5, 1],
    '2': ['monday', 2, 0],
    '3': ['tuesday', 1, 2],
    '4': ['tuesday', 3, 3]
}, orient='index', columns=['day', 'value',  'value1'])
print (df)
       day  value  value1
0   monday      1       4
1   monday      5       1
2   monday      2       0
3  tuesday      1       2
4  tuesday      3       3

categories=['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday', 'sunday']
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], categories=categories, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(['day','value']).drop_duplicates('day', keep='last')
print (df)
       day  value  value1
1   monday      5       1
4  tuesday      3       3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
print df.groupby('day',as_index=False)['value'].max()
```

Output:

```
       day  value
0   monday      5
1  tuesday      3
```

Comment: Look at the index it should be 1,4

Comment: That is actually not specified by OP @min2bro.

Comment: Check his output he has restored the index.

Comment: @min2bro - when using `as_index=False`, it will reset the index

Comment: Yeah, but OP hasn't said that it is required that output has the original index, it is just the result of the method OP uses.

Comment: @user3471881 - yeah I agree with you :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df.groupby(['day'])['value'].transform(max) == df['value']]
```

**Output:**

```
     day    value
1   Monday   5
4   Tuesday  3
```